# "review close votes" sounds grammatically incorrect

Tags: discussion, review, privileges, grammar

"Close Votes" is one of privileges. [This privilege level unlocks two review queues for questions that may need to be closed or reopened](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

The name/title of this privilege level, "review close votes", sounds grammatically incorrect. Both "review" and "close" are verbs in basic forms. That name is in this grammatical pattern `verb + verb + noun`, which sounds grammatically incorrect.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this instance, "Close Votes" is the subject of the "review." In other words, you're reviewing the "Close Votes" on various questions in this queue.

Remove "Close" from the scenario. Now, you have "Review Votes." Does that sound better?

"Close" in this instance is an adjective for "votes." It clarifies what kind of votes they are.

Also, "Close Votes" isn't necessarily the name of the privilege you're referencing. The exact privilege name is ["cast close and reopen votes."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

It's using the same scheme. You're "cast"-ing "votes." They just so happen to be "close" and "reopen" votes. They're adjectives to describe the type of vote.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful, thank you. And then, is "a close vote"  itself grammatical, `verb + noun` to get a compound noun?

Comment: My OP is just coming from your link, the section title "Reviewing close and reopen votes".

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes, a close vote is itself grammatically correct. Think of the term "swimming pool," a compound noun. While "swimming" may itself be a verb ("I am swimming!"), that's true, it's being used to describe what *type* of pool we're speaking about. So, then, when you're "reviewing" close and reopen votes, you're reviewing those two compound nouns. Does that help?

Comment: Why isn't it a "closing vote" then? I'm not sure it's grammatical, maybe it's jargon. Maybe it should be hyphenated neologism, a "close-vote". But that's more on-topic for https://english.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: Other examples of this structure in english: "See welcome sign", "Push off button"...

Comment: @ChrisW I'm in agreement that it could be a bit "more better" (heh... sorry, had to), but I would definitely bring it up over at [english SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), like you mentioned. Perhaps someone would be better than I am at explaining it.

Comment: "Swimming" is a gerund, not a verb. A gerund could be used as an adjective, a verb cannot.

Comment: Ah, I suppose you have me, @WXJ96163. Awful example. I would still bring this up on English SE... I'm obviously not capable of offering a full explanation.

Comment: @SteveBennett I read those two examples as quotes -- the name of the button, the text that's printed on the sign -- "See 'welcome' sign".

Comment: Apparently a [push-button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-button) is hyphenated or one word.

Comment: Try "welcome mat" then.